# MYSQL select same column name as alias as Number not working

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have create query something like bellow :

```
SELECT col_1 as "0", Col_2 as "1" FROM table
```

It is working when run in phpmyadmin but not work when run through php.
But when change as "zero" as "one" its working fine.

Any solution or suggestion.

I am using wordpress

```
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 
                'SELECT t.id,qrnumber ,
                tu.display_name,if(t.status=0,"---","Used") as "3" 
                FROM '.$table.' t 
                LEFT JOIN '.$table_wp.' tu ON tu.ID=t.user_id', ARRAY_A 
            );
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe there's a problem with your quoting in the PHP code. Show the code.

Comment: Use backticks instead of double quotes in MySQL.

Comment: please provide php code

Comment: I am using wordpress 
$results = $wpdb->get_results( 'SELECT t.id,qrnumber ,tu.display_name,if(t.status=0,"---","Used") as "3" FROM '.$table.' t LEFT JOIN '.$table_wp.' tu ON tu.ID=t.user_id', ARRAY_A );

Comment: Are you using `mysqli_fetch_array()` to fetch the results? The returned array has both numeric and named keys. If your column aliases are numbers, they'll conflict with the numeric keys.

Comment: Put the code in the question so we can read it more easily.

Comment: @Barmar i am usin wordpress on that no need to mysqi_fetch_array()

Comment: Maybe wordpress can't handle numeric aliases.

Comment: you put 2 different queries in your question. which is it? what is the error you get?

Comment: @backbone first is sample and second is actual query i am using. NO error getting.

Comment: I am seeing it working with lower version mysql but not working with higher version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma

```
SELECT col_1 as "0", Col_2 as "1" FROM table
```

Comment: He has a comma in the actual PHP code., this was probably just a copying error.